# what is correct approach to perform UI related task when a dialog gets dismissed

Tags: android

I have a dialog with `onDismiss` handler:

```
public class TextReaderDialog extends DialogFragment {
    ...

    public void onDismiss() {

    }
```

I show this dialog and add some styles to a part of text from the fragment:

```
TextReaderDialog d = new TextReaderDialog();
d.show(getFragmentManager(), "sample");

Spannable spannableText = new SpannableString(tv.getText());
spannableText.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.LTGRAY), startOffset, startOffset + w.word.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
tv.setText(spannableText);
```

Whenever a dialog is dismissed, I want to remove styles from the text. How can I do that? What is the correct way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to go about this would be to add a method to your fragment like so:

```
public void dismissStyles(){
    //do your style dismissing here
}
```

Now, I assume in the dialog you are overriding `DialogFragment.onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog)`. As long as that is the case, once you have completed that method, in your dialog's onDismiss function, you can do something to the effect of:

```
@Override
public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
    super.onDismiss(dialog);
    MyFragment fragment = (MyFragment) activity
         .getFragmentManager()
         .findFragmentByID(R.id.containerOfYourFragment);
    if(fragment != null){
         fragment.dismissStyles();
    }
}
```

Here, `activity` should be the current activity that your fragment and dialog are hosted in. You can pass this to the dialog in a constructor, or depending on where the dialog is located. You could also just pass the current fragment to the dialog in the constructor as well, and then it would simply be called by `myFragment.dismissStyles();`.

Comment: thanks, my dialog doesn't have `setOnDismissListener` method, why?

Comment: My mistake. I have edited my answer to reflect that you are using DialogFragment and not Dialog.

Comment: I still don't understand, should I myself implement `public void setOnDismissListener(final OnDismissListener onDismissListener) {` method on  my dialog?

Comment: I just made the change. You should be overriding `onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog)`.